# QGIS Hotspot Analysis plugin Error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, hot-spot

I am trying to install the hotspot analysis plugin but it keeps giving this error.

Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapes'

I am using QGIS 3.12, python 3.7 and pysal 1.14.3

Comment: Did you install pysal per the installation instructions? https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin#installation---windows\

Comment: Yes I followed the installation instructions.